# Make sent email functionality like github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, gmail

i'm using Rails 3.2 and i come cross a problem to find solution like github email system.
I want to make functionality in my Rails app **Forum** like if there are 10 members of one forum group and if any one reply through email the reply quotes should be post on all forum groups.

For example if we are 4 persons work on a github repo. And when one email come to all persons and if anyone reply of mail using gmail reply link the email goes to all persons who are working on this repo.

```
      some forums also use this functionality.
```

But i'm thinking that how control come to my app through gmail when anyone reply through gmail or anyother mailing server. i'm using gmail account currently.

Any ideas , blog posts ,refrences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're asking, "how can I have dynamically generated and maintained email lists?", right?  This is a deep, deep problem space.  I built just such a system a few years back, and it was a nightmare.  Email is very complicated.  Doing mailing lists right is very, very hard.  You need to deal with:

- Filtering out out-of-office responses
- Re-writing the emails to resend them
- Setting the proper mail headers
- Dealing with attachments
- The hundred and one types of email encoding
- Outlook... oh god, Outlook

It's not an easy problem to solve.  My recommendation would be to google around for a 3rd party provider with a good email list management API that you could pay to handle this for you.

Rolling your own would be a last resort...